# How can I count the letters and get the percentage of each letter's existence in a file with python?

Tags: python

```
mydict={"a":5,"b":1,"c":4, "d":3, "e":6}
def get_letter_percentage(dictionary, s):
    sum=0
    for key in dictionary:
        sum += dictionary[key]
    return float(dictionary[s])/float(sum)
```

Comment: Looks like you already counted them?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: could you please elaborate? what is your issue? are you stuck?

Comment: Can't understand. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to calculate the `%` of each letter from your dic

```
mydict={"a":5,"b":1,"c":4, "d":3, "e":6}
def get_letter_percentage(dictionary,givenkey):
    sum=0
    for key in dictionary:
        sum += dictionary[key]
    return(dictionary[givenkey]/sum*100)

>>> get_letter_percentage(mydict,'a')
26.31578947368421

>>> get_letter_percentage(mydict,'b')
5.263157894736842

>>> get_letter_percentage(mydict,'c')
21.052631578947366
```